# Randbetween in excel and their standard sum

Tags: excel, sum

I use the RANDBETWEEN(;) to find random numbers of oil of a month that each number has to be up to 500 litters. The total amount of oil I have used, in a month is e.g 7000 liters and I want to find how much oil I used for each day. Everyday has to have different numbers and their sum has to be the standard total I already have which is e.g. 7000 liters. How I can do this automatically in excel? And I have to calculate this for every month in one year...

Comment: This is more of a simulation / algorithms kind of a question. Not the right place. Plus, show what you've already done so people can help. This is a problem solving forum and the approach to problem solving isn't "Give me the solution"

Answer (score 0):

This is for a **31** day month.

In **A1** thru **A31** enter `=RANDBETWEEN(1,500)`

In **A32** enter:  `=SUM(A1:A31)`

**A1** thru **A31** are random samples, but may not have the proper sum so:

In **B1** enter: `=ROUND(A1*7000/$A$32,0)`  and copy down thru **B30**

Finally in **B31** enter:  `=7000-SUM(B1:B30)`

**B1** thru **B31** represent 31 random samples that will sum to 7000.